# jQuery optimized for iPad?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a web app for the iPad and most of the effects I've been using are from jQuery. Not all the animations are smooth though, which is why I'm wondering if there is a version of jQuery that is optimized to run smoother on the iPad?

Comment: you have to make css3 animations. Sorry for my lame answer. I haven't been sleeping for almost 2 days now. (48h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's jQuery mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/

Also, CSS3 animations as per AndreasAL's comment. Use those instead of JavaScript where possible.

Useful article for CSS3 animations with 'normal' (not mobile) jQuery fallbacks; should be applicable to your scenario: http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/ Note, however, that many mobile devices have a cache size limit that is exceeded by 'normal' jQuery. Not sure about iPad.

[update follows]

I came across [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) quite a while ago but forgot about this SO answer until someone bumped it. In many cases, Zepto.js is a drop-in replacement for mobile jQuery-based applications. It is compatible beyond mobile to a limited degree (it's actually for webkit, which default browsers for iOS and Android use), but I wouldn't rely on it for desktop users. You could use a conditional preloader (require.js?) to load jQuery for desktop and Zepto for mobile.

Worst case, drop it in, see if it works for your needs; the syntax is jQuery-compatible so you won't need to modify your custom code just to see if it works.

[further update]

If you're doing user agent detection or this is ONLY going to be for iOS and Android, there's also this:

http://www.jqmobi.com/

Comment: The problem with jQ mobile is that I'd have to rewrite most of my code to work with it. I might try to switch some of the effects to CSS3, just not sure if there's a div flip one (I'll google it). What do you mean about the cache limit?

Comment: So generally once you've fetched a script (or other resource), the browser can cache it so that it doesn't need to fetch it again on another page. For individual components, iPhone doesn't (last I checked) cache anything larger than 25KB. I just noticed at least one researcher who said it's actually 15KB. I don't claim to be an expert, but I've read many times that jQuery exceeds iPhone limits. I generalized that probably other mobile devices have a similar issue. Again, though, not sure about iPad.

Comment: Updated this answer with the bit about Zepto.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll definitely look into Zepto, and I'll mark this as the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this easing jquery plugins optimized for hard animation effects and gives you smooth animation effect

see [here](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Comment: How would I implement this? Would I need to rewrite existing code or simply call the script in the head?

Comment: Adding it does not seem to make the animations smoother

Comment: @Charlie..Please go through the link

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try dropping the refresh rate of the animations, which you can do like this:

```
//animate memory hog fix
jQuery.fx.prototype.custom = function(from, to, unit) {
    this.startTime = now();
    this.start = from;
    this.end = to;
    this.unit = unit || this.unit || "px";
    this.now = this.start;
    this.pos = this.state = 0;
    var self = this;
    function t(gotoEnd) {
        return self.step(gotoEnd);
    }
    t.elem = this.elem;
    if (t() && jQuery.timers.push(t) && !jQuery.fx.prototype.timerId) {
        jQuery.fx.prototype.timerId = setInterval(jQuery.fx.tick, 75);
    }
}
```

Change 75 on that last line to whatever you want. Also be careful what you're animating, just try and do one thing at a time. Opacity is always a memory hog, so try substituting slide effects where you can.

Comment: Will this work for all jQuery animations? And it'd just be put in the head tag right?

Comment: Yes it changes the timers for all jQuery animations, including the built in ones like slide(). Just put it in the head after your jquery include.

Comment: Putting it after breaks some of my code. Putting it before does not but that is probably because it is being overridden...

Comment: I don't receive an error but I was using it in conjunction with the Flip! jQ plugin, which it broke. I'll try it with other animations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [jQuery Animate Enhanced Plugin](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) by Ben Barnett

Comment: I like this. It might work for some parts but not all, and for the ones it doesn't work for (Flip! plugin for example) it screws it up.